# Play music from Android to Airplay receiver

Tags: music, streaming, airplay

Is there a way of playing music on my Android phone to an Airplay receiver (like Airport Express etc)?

Comment: If Airplay is compatible with the UPnP specification, you may try an UPnP app such as [UPnPlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cx.hoohol.silanoid&feature=search_result) (free) or [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp&feature=search_result) (paid).

Comment: Thanks @Cutter, I tried UPnPlay but couldn't find the devices. It was able to find music on my laptop which was neat though.

Answer (score 2):

The [Airsync add-on to the Double Twist player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayerProKey) adds this ability. It's not free, but was worth it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Airsync supports the Apple TV, but no other Airplay devices.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to AirTwist, but either way it appears to only support the Apple TV and Sonos http://www.doubletwist.com/help/question/what-devices-are-supported-by-doubletwist-airplay/